# What does "one or two generations removed from the real pioneer days" mean?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

> My mother and the other women I knew as a child, just before World War II began, were farm women, **one or two generations removed from the real pioneer days**, gentled and domesticated by the time I came among them. *(From ACT)*

Does the text in bold modifying "farm women"? And what does the bold text mean anyway, “removed from the real pioneer days"?

Comment: A "generation" here means "average time between ***being born*** and ***giving birth***". So it's not to do with how long people live - it's to do with how long before the next generation gets born (generally supposed to be about 20 years). So those farm women were born 20-40 years later than "the real pioneer days" of the early settlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of this sentence is "My mother and the other women I knew as a child." After the verb "were", there are three different phrases that all modify that same subject:

1. farm women
2. one or two generations removed from the real pioneer days
3. gentled and domesticated by the time I came among them

This is a somewhat poetic construction where you can leave out a conjunction in a list, in this case a list of adjective phrases. Here's a much simpler sentence with the same structure:

> The cat is soft, warm, quiet.

Normally, you'd put an "and" before the final modifying word/phrase, but omitting the conjunction creates one of a number of [stylistic effects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124480/lists-without-and).  In your example, it emphasizes that this a list of highly interrelated qualities.

The word [removed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/removed) can mean "separate or remote in space, time, or character."  Here, the writer is saying that while the parents or grandparents of the women he's writing about (that is, **one or two generations removed** in time) could have been said to live in the **real pioneer days**, but the women themselves are from a more modern time.  They are therefore more **gentled and domesticated** than their near ancestors from the **real pioneer days**.